# How to Convert HWND's Bitmap'd X, Y into a Mouse Event dX, dY?

Tags: c++, directx

I'm Processing batches of Images and scanning them for a pattern of pixels.  I can get the program to work with SetCursorPos() and it works perfect, but I'm adapting the tech to live motion feed.  SerCursorPos() does not work with that window, but mouse_event does work.

My Issue: Where it was easy to pass the X,Y of the Bitmap to SetCursorPos, I've tried a few formulas to convert and provide the x, y to dX and dY for mouse_event, but they seem to be off by 70-100 coordinates or pixels.  For Example I've tried using the HWND's RECT as a base for width and hieght applied against 65535; and that didn't work.  Should I be using a GetSystemMetric of the window?  Any help would be appreciated. Should I use a DirectX alternative?

Comment: Do you mean the image jumps away when you click directly on it?

Answer (score 0):

At least if I understand what you're asking, it sounds like you're looking for [`ClientToScreen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183434.aspx) (and possibly doing some compensation for the position of the bitmap inside the client area).